# Varying RI Constraints between 3 tables. How does deletion in table A affect table C?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please Refer Below Image,

[image]

*Manager attribute refers to the ID attribute in the employee table and Project refers to the Code attribute in the project table.*

Suppose Manager has an ON DELETE CASCADE and Project attribute has an ON DELETE RESTRICT. What would happen if you deleted an employee who was a manager whose project is in the potential customers table?

Comment: You tagged this as Oracle. Oracle does not have "ON DELETE RESTRICT", where did you find that?

Comment: @mathguy - you're right in that you don't specify "ON DELETE RESTRICT" as you would "ON DELETE CASCADE", but just consider "restrict" as the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle will go down the chain of references and will stop on on "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found" if it finds a "restricted" foreign key constraint.

If all FK constraints in the chain were defined as "CASCADE", rows in PROJECT associated with manager ids matching deleted rows in EMPLOYEE would also be deleted and similarly, rows in POTENTIAL_CUSTOMERS having project ids that were deleted in PROJECT would also be deleted.